# Usage of heap memory for android app

Tags: android, memory

I used following APIs to check memory that my app can use and got the below results.

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
    Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
    Log.v("onCreate", "memoryClass:" + Integer.toString(memoryClass));
```

V/onCreate: maxMemory:402653184

V/onCreate: memoryClass:64

But when I launch my app, it shows 5MB allocated and 1 MB free.
I was in assumption that entire 64 MB will be for the app and suppose if 5MB is allocated out of 64MB then 59MB should be free.

And as I progress using the application, the heap size allocated is growing with lot of GC causes in between which is impacting the UI performance.

Could someone make me understand this process.

Will this work this way?

Thanks